Pinned android flutter app does not produce sound when i trigger a notification
I'm using AwesomeNotifications to create a notification with sound in my flutter android app.
This works perfectly when the app is not pinned but when i pin the app it does not produce any sound.
        // Triggering the notification
        AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
          content: NotificationContent(
              customSound: "resource://raw/level1v2",
              id: 10,
              channelKey: 'high_importance_id',
              title: 'Alerte!',
              body: "test"),
        );

I tried to run the app in debug mode to see if there is any errors but the code run without issue, its just the sound that does not play.
Is there a specific feature that disable notifications when an android app is pinned ?
I'm using a google pixel tablet to do my tests.
Unpinned app = notification sound is good
Pinned app   = notification sound does not play
Tried running the app in debug mode with no success.
Allowed this specific notification to goes through do not disturb with no success.
